# Unexpected error when proguard the jsoup in android

Tags: android, proguard, jsoup

My android project have Jsoup(1.6.1) as the external library, but proguard(with the default proguard.cfg generated by ADT) tells there are unexpected errors, such as:

> [proguard] Unexpected error while evaluating instruction:
>
> [proguard]   Class       = [org/jsoup/parser/TreeBuilder]
>
> [proguard]   Method      = [insertInFosterParent(Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Node;)V]
>
> [proguard]   Instruction = [64] aload_2 v2
>
> [proguard]   Exception   = [java.lang.NullPointerException] (null)
>
> [proguard] Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
>
> [proguard]   Class       = [org/jsoup/parser/TreeBuilder]
>
> [proguard]   Method      = [insertInFosterParent(Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Node;)V]
>
> [proguard]   Exception   = [java.lang.NullPointerException] (null)

I have found many posts with the similiar issue for other libraries, and -dontoptimize can remove such errors, but it would degrade the optimization (as the default value in proguard.cfg: -optimizationpasses 5)

Anyone could help me on this? or is it a potential issue of Jsoup?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.
Resolved it by using the [latest version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/proguard/) of Proguard (4.6) instead of the version bundled with the android sdk (4.4).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in ProGuard. You should check if it hasn't been fixed in the latest release. Otherwise, you can report the bug on [ProGuard](https://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/)'s bug tracker at Sourceforge. In this case, the problem may be easy to reproduce. You can probably work around it by reducing the number of optimization passes.